# Better way to represent the date in oracle query

Tags: oracle

Is there any better way to restart the below query of oracle in a better way, below is the query

```
UPDATE ABC SET STATUS='CLEAN' 
 WHERE STATUS in ('RUNNING','HALT') 
   AND START_DATE BETWEEN to_date(to_char(sysdate-1 , 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                      and to_date(to_char(sysdate-4 , 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 6):

Although correct I don't like casting a `DATE` into a `CHAR` and back again to a DATE. Note `sysdate-1` is greater than `sysdate-4`, thus your condition will **never** be true. Try this one:

```
START_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate-4) AND TRUNC(sysdate-1);
```